# Use different versions of Python packages depending on the plugin that is used

Tags: python, python-2.7, plugins, import

I have a Python GUI that can load and run plugin packages at runtime. A plugin package is simply a Python package that includes all additional libraries that the plugin code needs. These additional libraries are stored in a site-packages subfolder of the plugin. The file structure of a typical plugin would be like this:

```
myplugin/__init__.py
myplugin/plugin_main.py
myplugin/site-packages/foolib/__init__.py
myplugin/site-packages/foolib/foo_main.py
```

In order to make plugin_main.py able to import libraries like foolib I've added the site-packages subdirectory to PYTHONPATH by adding this code in plugin_main.py:

```
import sys
packages_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "site-packages")
sys.path.insert(1, packages_path)
import foolib
```

So far, so good. This works basically. The issue is that, if the GUI loads a second plugin that should import its own version of foolib, actually the foolib version from the first plugin gets used instead. In other words: Even if different plugins come with different versions of foolib in their site-packages subfolder, it is always the same version that is used in the GUI.

What I need is that when the GUI loads myplugin, then foolib from myplugin/site-packages should be used. If I load myotherplugin afterwards then it should use foolib from myotherplugin/site-packages, not from myplugin/site-packages. I hope I made the problem clear.

Would the [imp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#) package help in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to realize that there is no safe way to achieve what I tried to do. Instead, I ended up to move each plugin into a separate process using Python multiprocessing. That was actually very easy to do and is probably the cleanest solution anyway.